# Extracting words from a Document into a HashSet in Java

Tags: java, file, extract

I am trying to understand how to put every words of a file into a HashSet. The method I am writing should read the file and return words found in the file as a HashSet. I also have to use the method split() but can't figure out how to use it. And I also have a normalize() method that converts all words into lowercase. This is how far I got:

```
public static HashSet<String> extractWordsFromDocument(String filename) {
    try {
       FileReader in = new FileReader(filename);
      Scanner file = new Scanner(in);
      while(file.hasNext( )){
        try {
          String line = file.nextLine();
          line = line.normalize();
          line = line.split();
          Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
          hashset.add(line);
          System.out.println(words);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
      }
    }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    }
    return null;
  }
```

I know there's a lot of mistakes in this code. I am just a beginner...

Comment: What do you think the split() method does? It seems you don't know. The solution is to read its javadoc. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html. Also, you're createing a new HashSet for *every line*. And printing the contents of this set *at every line*. The HashSet should be created before the loop, and returned after the loop. Your method currently always returns null. Also, stop catching exceptions. Declare IOException in the throws clause.

Comment: Oh, and where did you learn that String had a normalize() method? Again, read the javadoc. That method doesn't exist.

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah I forgot to mention that I had a helper method called normalize() that convert the words into lowercase

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the `HashSet` inside your loop, it means you will have a new one for each line in the file, and each one will contain only the words in that line.

Also, you could make better use of the `Scanner`, which has a [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) method that will give you the words separated by blank space (space, tab, line endings, etc.), which is the default delimiter.

And remember to close your resources. Starting with Java 7, you can use the [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Also, [don't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding) [swallow](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2003/04/28/swallowing_exceptions_dont_do_it/) [your](https://dzone.com/articles/the-curse-swallowed-exception) [exceptions](http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf).

```
public static Set<String> extractWordsFromDocument(String filename) throws IOException {
    try (Reader in = new FileReader(filename)) {
        Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
        while (scanner.hasNext()){
            words.add(scanner.next());
        }
        return words;
    }
}
```

If you want to know how [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) or [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) works, [read the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)...